# Добавить кнопку импорта из файла в модель в админке Django

Tags: python, django, django-admin

В админке есть стандартные кнопки: "Add" и "Change", возле моделей, как к одной из моделей добавить третью "Import" и сделать страничку с одним большим текстовым полем и кнопкой загрузки файла на выбор? Потом функцией распарсить текст по полям модели по нажатии кнопки "Import this data".

Как это реализовать, какие файлы редактировать, если можно по шагам, пожалуйста.

Comment: Полный ответ писать нет времени, извините, но посмотрите раздел [overriding admin templates](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#overriding-admin-templates).

Вам надо переопределить блок, если не путаю, `{% block object-tools %}` в `admin/change_list.html`, добавив туда собственную кнопку. Ну и в своем application'е сделать форму и вид для импортирования (каком-нибудь `yourproject.my_admin.{forms,views}`).

Перед всем этим почитайте как устроена админка в исходниках Django. Качаете архив и смотрите в `django/contrib/admin/`. Только не патчите там ничего — это важно.

Comment: Не патчить — потому что когда придет время обновить Django (а оно, если проект не «сейчас использовать для разовой задачи и на выброс» придет), то с патченной джангой все будет обстоять несколько неприятно. Как однажды попавший в такую ситуацию — не рекомендую. По крайней мере без Git и отдельного бранча для своих правок, который можно будет смерджить с апстримом.

По той же причине — при переопределении шаблонов, как можно меньше копируйте кода, и как можно больше используйте механизмы наследования.

Comment: Добавил кнопку. Теперь в urls.py добавляю чтото вроде /admin/import/ 'app.admin.py' ? Создаю там функцию с таблицей.. html код? Тут мои мысли обрываются. Можно подробней или мануал, может тутор есть. Спасибо

Comment: Тутор в первом комменте. Оверрайдите шаблон, и все. Больше ничего не надо

Comment: Ага сделал оверрид, добавил шаблон, в нем форма, textarea и задумался над кнопкой submit, как вызывать функцию которая будет обрабатывать то что в textarea, а потом сохранять в модель save(), где эту функцию писать и что делать и как делаются submit кнопки?